# Model reduction - Backward elimination

Tags: mixed-model, sas, fitting, covariance-matrix, polynomial

The rule I use for reducing covariates (trimming) is as following:

1. Look at the highest order interaction. If that is not significant, drop it.  If it is significant, stop.
2. If drop the highest order interaction (because insignificant), look at the highest order polynomial. If not significant you drop it, if it is significant you keep it.
3. Continue the process.

But before that, I need to pick the model with best variance-covariance structure. This step determines the highest order polynomial and interaction (which goes in the MODEL statement), as well as the variance-covariance structure (which goes in the RANDOM statement). Criteria for picking are BIC/AIC, and whether v-c structure is estimable.

Assume the model with best v-c looks like:

```
PROC mixed covtest;
    CLASS id treatment;
    MODEL outcome = treatment time treatment*time timesquare treatment*timesquare 
                    timecubic treatment*timecubic / ddfm=kenwardroger s;
    RANDOM intercept timecubic/ type=un subject=subj g gcorr s;
RUN;
```

So, I begin to trim applying rules above. The scenario is:

1. treatment*timecubic is not significant, I then drop it from model rerun the model w/out it.
2. Look at timecubic in the new model, it's not significant.

Now the highest order interaction and polynomial corresponding to the order of the variable in RANDOM STATEMENT are excluded (timecubic). How should I proceed with this?

- Should I drop timecubic in RANDOM STATEMENT and start again with picking best c-v model, but ignoring cubic and higher order of time?
- Or, should I keep timecubic and proceed with the rest of variables in MODEL STATEMENT?

If possible, please suggest some reading that may be useful.

EDITED: Thanks Glen_b for suggestions.

Comment: "trimming" is a term with a [specific meaning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trimmed_estimator) in statistics. It means something other than what you're using it to mean -- it means to remove the most extreme observations before carrying out some procedure. What you're talking about sounds like a form of model reduction that is related to backward elimination.

Comment: Thanks, Glen. Let's say then the jargon is not accurate, but do you have some solution for this problem?

Comment: On the overall idea, a reading of Chapter 4 of Harrell's *Regression Modelling Strategies* may give you a different perspective.